# Vaadin 24.04 logging Broadcaster messages repeatedly

Tags: vaadin, atmosphere, vaadin24

I just upgraded my Vaadin app from 23.x to 24.x and and correspondingly upgraded my runtime environment with Tomcat 10.1.8.

I'm using `@Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC)` and my Servlet uses the following

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyApp", asyncSupported = true, initParams = {
    @WebInitParam(name = "productionMode", value = "true"),
    @WebInitParam(name = "heartbeatInterval", value = "30"),
    @WebInitParam(name = "closeIdleSessions", value = "false")})
```

I am getting the following repeatedly logged and my UI is sluggish. is there something else I need to configure or need to change for the upgrade to Vaadin 24.x to fix this issue or is this a bug?

```
Atmosphere-Shared-0] WARN org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster - This message Entry{message=com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.AtmospherePushConnection$PushMessage@65df019a, type=RESOURCE, future=org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterFuture@4dfa5742} will be lost
[Atmosphere-Shared-0] WARN org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster - Failed to submit broadcast handler runnable to for Broadcaster/*
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.checkFacade(RequestFacade.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeader(RequestFacade.java:505)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:82)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.getHeader(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:351)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.getHeader(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:336)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.LongPollingCacheFilter.filter(LongPollingCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterConfig.filter(BroadcasterConfig.java:452)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.perRequestFilter(DefaultBroadcaster.java:818)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.deliverPush(DefaultBroadcaster.java:691)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.push(DefaultBroadcaster.java:568)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$1.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:423)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
```

I haven't found any other reference to this logging error other than a configuration with Spring but my app doesn't use Spring

Comment: I did some playing around in my code with the number of UI updates and drastically reduced the number of updates just to see what would happen. The errors went away so there is something different between V23 and V24 on how often updates can be pushed to the UI. 

I'm not sure what I can really ask about settings for the UI but does anyone know of any settings that can adjust how the UI gets updated  - perhaps increase buffer values? I must be throwing too many updates at it although it worked fine with V23.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: this is my question about the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75685936/vaadin-24-long-polling-push-and-failed-to-submit-broadcast-handler-runnable-to-f

Comment: No real solution yet other than "slowing down" the rate of pushes. I'm stuck with Tomcat for now so switching to Undertow is not an option for me. I've also updated to Vaadin 24.0.5 but nothing changed. How do we get the developers at Vaadin to note this issue?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to create an issue on Vaadin github. Vaadin developers are very helpful and responsive.

Comment: Please post the link here on the GitHub issue in the comments too, because I would like to subscribe as well

Comment: I opened this issue:https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16775